# Connect with Remote Desktop viewer after reboot

Tags: vnc

I have a computer with Fedora 24 that I often use to control another remote comptuer with Fedora 23.
I can use `vinagre` to do this, provided that I log in at least once with my user in my remote computer. Normally I have physical access to the remote computer, so I just turn it on and log in, and then whenever I want I can remotely control it.

Sometiemes, however, I need to reboot the remote computer. When this happens I cannot directly use `vinagre` (I can use `ssh` but I really need the interface). The problem is that soon I will not have access to my remote computer, so I'm looking for a way to solve this. My understanding is that I need to start up the vino server in the remote computer, but I don't know how to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would imagine there's a service file for vino. If you SSH in and use `systemctl start vino.service` what happens?

Comment: @I_GNU_it_all_along, I'm getting "Failed to start vino.service: Unit vino.service failed to load: No such file or directory." Are you sure this should be the command? Vino is installed

Comment: Hmm, looks like vino doesn't ship with a service file then... Unless it's actually called something like `vino-server.service`? Is there a requirement to use VNC? Or are you open to better alternatives?

Comment: @I_GNU_it_all_along I am also open to other alternatives, especially if they are better!

Comment: No problem, added it as an answer.

Comment: Just revisiting some questions, how did you get on with this?

Comment: @I_GNU_it_all_along I was not able to make X2go work, not sure why. I looked into alternatives and now I am using TigerVnc

Comment: Hmm, I see. Well, I'm glad you got a working solution in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend moving off of VNC and onto [X2go](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php) or another, similar implementation of [FreeNX](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX).

VNC is often slow, unresponsive, unreliable and often less secure than this alternative which is much speedier, more reliable and carried out through SSH X11 forwarding so is pretty much as secure as your installation of SSH. Also, I've personally experienced zero graphical issues over X2go whereas when using VNC I've struggled with constant graphical bugs.

If someone jumps in and provides a working solution for your VNC problem that's great but I'd still say you'd be better off to get rid altogether.